# Squid not blocking access to websites

Tags: proxy, squid, block, blocking

I'm on Ubuntu Server 22.04.3 LTS and I'm trying to learn a bit about Squid.

I installed Squid v5.7 and one of my tasks is to deny access to a list of URL's.

I modified "squid.conf" file and added the following after *"# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS"*:

```
acl bad_url dstdomain "/etc/squid/bad-sites.acl"
http_access deny bad_url
```

After that I created `bad-sites.acl` file in /etc/squid/ and there I inserted:

```
.xpto.com
.abc123.com
.facebook.com
```

Next, I restarted Squid with the command `sudo systemctl restart squid.service`.

However I'm still able to access any of these 3 websites.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of entering `sudo systemctl status squid.service`. That should show if the service stayed up and may show whether it actually loaded your  `bad-sites.acl` file. There should also be a log file which may have information about what's happening.

Comment: It looks like you did it correctly so please Review Squid's logs for any errors or warnings:

Comment: The filter should be in regexp but it is still OK in this case. Did you set up proxy in browser or system properly? how about the `access.log` and `cache.log`?

Comment: I found the problem. I hadn't correctly set up the proxy in the system. Now it is working! Thanks for your answers guys!